# Why is Promise.all returning [ [Function: test1], [Function: test2] ]

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm learning Promises:

```
Promise.all([
      test1,
      test2
    ]).then((res)=>{
      resolve(res);
    })
```

Above code doesn't return the value but a pointer to the function:
`[ [Function: test1], [Function: test2] ]`

Why is that? The asynchronous nature of JS is difficult to grasp

Full code snippet and further explanation below:

```js
module.exports = function main(dbo, tickers, quotes) {
    const arr = tickers.split(',');
    let underlyingPrice = 0;
    let collection = '';
    let obj = {};
    arr.forEach((ticker) => {
      if (quotes[ticker].assetType === 'EQUITY') {
        Object.assign(obj, {
          [ticker]: {}
        })
        underlyingPrice = quotes[ticker].regularMarketLastPrice;
        collection = dbo.collection(`priceHistory-${ticker}`);
        getfastMA(underlyingPrice, collection);
        getslowMA(underlyingPrice, collection);
      }
    })
    Promise.all([
      getfastMA,
      getslowMA
    ]).then((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
    })
}
```

What I want to happen:

1. `arr.forEach` loops through an array, grabs ticker and passes onto `getfastMA` and `getslowMA` functions. those functions execute mongodb query that contains data for that specific ticker. Also, those **functions calculate averages** as `Promise`
2. the two functions are `Promise` which I want to resolve together once the loop above has exited
3. Save the averages into an obj.
   What I actually get is:
   `[ [Function: getfastMA], [Function: getslowMA] ]`
   I saw several YouTube videos, that I thought I was duplicating the syntax but obviously I'm not

Comment: because, at a guess, test1, test2 are functions .... did you mean to do `test1(), test2()` to run some function that returns a promise

Comment: Presumably because you forgot to *call* those functions, try `Promise.all([test1(), test2()]).then(...)`.

Comment: And you could also remove the `new Promise` antipattern.

Comment: @Thomas - what `new Promise` anti-pattern? can you see code we can't :p - oh, wait, yes, I see where that is implied

Comment: You want to add the result of `getfastMA` and `getslowMA` into an array, then pass that array to `Promise.all`. So something like `const getMAs = []; arr.forEach(... getMAs.push(getfastMA(underlyingPrice, collection)); getMAs.push(getslowMA(underlyingPrice, collection));}); Promise.all(getMAs).then((MAs => /* do something with results */);`

Comment: Oh my @HereticMonkey. dude that worked! you ain't Heretic at all! Would love to understand how you thought of it. I'm assuming you're advanced JS person.

Comment: I've done some JavaScript before, yes :). It's part of what I do for a living. But mostly, I just read documentation. For instance, [MDN's docs on `Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) show that it takes an array of promises. Since you mentioned that `getfastMA` returned a promise, I just figured that you could stuff that in an array. Ditto with `getslowMA`. The rest is just plumbing :).

Answer (score 1):

Probably `test1` is and `test2` are your promise returning functions and you do not call them to return promises to hand in to `Promise.all` as you try to do. `Promise.all` requires an array of promises as one argument. So one needs to call these functions somewhere and pass the promises in an array to `.all` method. Following example calls them inline.

```
Promise.all([
      test1(),
      test2()
    ]).then((res)=>{
      resolve(res);
    })
```

With your post update use your `get*` named functions instead. However, again, do not forget to call them for example like my above code so that you have the promises they return and so that the `Promise.all` can work with that. `Then` it will return you what each promise returns if they `all` settle fulfilled.

Comment: I like to put the full block of code, but Stack gives me a mesg 'your post is all code.' How can I put the block of code? Thanks

Comment: @DwayneJackson — You need to supply a [mcve]. It needs to be complete enough to demonstrate the problem without being so minimal that the problem can't be reproduced. Nobody here is being paid enough to wade through a huge pile of raw code.

Comment: Your example code was almost enough when it has only the similar snippet I have used in my answer. Only shortage was what exactly was test1 test2 was not clear? Were they functions, promises, what they return: promises, functions, etc.